# If 'happy' is without a noun

Tags: word-usage

If adjective 'happy' is without a noun, does this word still have a meaning or have no meaning without a noun?

Comment: Give a context where you would use happy without a noun. "happy" is an adjective and as such will always describe a noun or pronoun, whether they are expressed in the sentence or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If adjective 'happy' is without a noun, does this word still have a meaning or have no meaning without a noun?

'**She is happy**' (pronoun, verb, adjective) is a perfectly common sentence I'm sure you understand and has meaning.

'**It is good to be happy**' (pronoun, verb, adjective, preposition, verb, adjective) is also meaningful and has no noun.

I'm guessing that the source of your question comes from the fact that 'happiness' is a state of contentment that only a living being can experience, so you may think there must be a subject or an object that is feeling that emotion whenever you mention it. As my examples show, you can indicate a subject without a noun, and you can also speak about 'being happy' in an abstract sense. However, as an *emotion* you can't use it in place of other adjectives like 'pleasant' - you couldn't say that the weather was happy, for example.

Comment: Does the downvoter want to give some feedback as to what is the problem?

Comment: I have not downvoted but I do believe the too vague question did not help you answer very relevantly.

Comment: @fev I agree the question isn't perfect, but I felt I understood it (and judging by the fact they accepted my answer, I must have). I think we have to make some concessions for the fact that those asking the questions are not native speakers themselves. If they could express themselves perfectly in English, they wouldn't be here.

Comment: I perfectly agree, I am not a native speaker myself! However, I just wanted to encourage the OP to specify that he or she is referring to a case of noun or pronoun elision, which seems to be the case since your answer was accepted. When the OP does that, it might establish the relevancy of your answer. I was asked to review this question, and this is the problem I found.

Comment: Good answer - I've voted for it, but there is one more thing you could add.  We cannot say "It is happy that ..." - whereas we can say "It is sad that ...", "It is terrible that ...", "It is fortunate that ...", "It is lucky that ...".  ("Happily" adv. works fine, though = fortunately: "Happily, the letter arrived before the deadline.")

Comment: @rjpond Good point, I've added something to that effect, but tried to keep it in the spirit of the already-accepted answer. I don't want to confuse matters, the OP is evidently happy with it.